# R Error Invalid type (list) for variable

Tags: r, matlab, machine-learning

I am import matlab file and construct a data frame, matlab file contains two columns with and each row maintain a cell that has a matrix, I construct a dataframe to run random forest. But I am getting following error.

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = expert_data_frame$t_labels ~ .,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'expert_data_frame$t_labels'
```

Here is the code how I import the matlab file and construct the dataframe:

```
all_exp_traintest <- readMat(all_exp_filepath);
len = length(all_exp_traintest$exp.traintest)/2;
    for (i in 1:len) {
      expert_train_df <- data.frame(all_exp_traintest$exp.traintest[i]);
      labels = data.frame(all_exp_traintest$exp.traintest[i+302]);
      names(labels)[1] <- "t_labels";
      expert_train_df$t_labels <- labels;
      expert_data_frame <- data.frame(expert_train_df);
      rf_model = randomForest(expert_data_frame$t_labels ~., data=expert_data_frame, importance=TRUE, do.trace=100);
    }
```

Structure of the Matlab input file

```
[56x12 double]    [56x1 double]
[62x12 double]    [62x1 double]
[62x12 double]    [62x1 double]
[62x12 double]    [62x1 double]
[62x12 double]    [62x1 double]
[74x12 double]    [74x1 double]


> str(all_exp_traintest)
List of 1
 $ exp.traintest:List of 604
  ..$ NA: num [1:56, 1:12] 0 0 0 0 8 1 1 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:62, 1:12] 2 10 11 13 5 10 13 8 11 8 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:62, 1:12] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:62, 1:12] 4 2 1 3 3 20 6 3 2 2 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:62, 1:12] 2731 2362 2937 1229 1898 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:74, 1:12] 27 33 34 38 33 35 36 35 47 46 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:74, 1:12] 106 79 99 94 153 104 146 105 125 146 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:74, 1:12] 3 9 3 0 1 26 0 4 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:51, 1:12] 5 7 3 30 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:66, 1:12] 0 0 13 0 0 3 2 2 0 2 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:73, 1:12] 1 0 1 0 0 0 2 1 2 5 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:73, 1:12] 23 14 20 14 24 22 32 61 84 278 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:75, 1:12] 1 7 0 1 2 3 3 0 16 10 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:90, 1:12] 10 7 8 15 25 12 37 31 18 48 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:90, 1:12] 0 6 3 1 5 7 8 6 1 1 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:90, 1:12] 0 1 1 2 0 4 9 6 3 4 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:90, 1:12] 6 0 5 27 11 50 22 8 10 4 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:90, 1:12] 3 9 13 12 4 0 5 0 5 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:90, 1:12] 1 0 1 0 1 2 1 0 1 2 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:90, 1:12] 3395 3400 3360 3770 3533 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:84, 1:12] 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 5 4 2 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:80, 1:12] 2 3 3 3 4 28 61 26 8 1 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:81, 1:12] 4 28 22 9 16 43 80 21 19 18 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:76, 1:12] 1 0 0 1 49 64 60 230 222 267 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:76, 1:12] 4786 4491 2510 1144 2071 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:76, 1:12] 80 128 254 109 114 267 152 139 368 363 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:76, 1:12] 1 5 8 2 14 5 3 13 8 2 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:76, 1:12] 10 3 8 79 4 4 11 30 2 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:68, 1:12] 0 0 2 0 0 2 6 0 0 4 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:68, 1:12] 1 4 5 2 2 3 3 1 3 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:68, 1:12] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:69, 1:12] 39 45 2 0 1 4 3 0 13 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:69, 1:12] 0 4 6 0 0 4 1 6 10 1 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:69, 1:12] 0 2 5 2 2 2 0 0 3 6 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:69, 1:12] 3 0 1 1 1 4 7 5 5 1 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:66, 1:12] 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 5 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:66, 1:12] 4 3 3 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:65, 1:12] 0 0 1 0 0 0 5 8 4 1 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:65, 1:12] 0 5 6 0 2 0 0 1 1 2 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:69, 1:12] 0 16 5 1 14 0 1 0 0 16 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:69, 1:12] 0 0 0 0 0 25 2 3 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:64, 1:12] 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:42, 1:12] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:67, 1:12] 0 2 4 10 15 4 1 43 1 7 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:63, 1:12] 32 6 12 5 92 8 29 7 21 20 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:63, 1:12] 2 5 12 8 10 13 6 11 10 14 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:63, 1:12] 3 5 10 9 0 1 8 13 2 14 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:54, 1:12] 0 0 14 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:82, 1:12] 152 99 63 57 105 44 28 33 43 49 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:81, 1:12] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:75, 1:12] 0 1 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:75, 1:12] 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:75, 1:12] 1 6 5 5 3 8 1 3 1 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:72, 1:12] 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 2 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:62, 1:12] 310 91 4 4 9 0 0 1 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:62, 1:12] 239 374 1060 599 805 808 139 150 490 326 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:49, 1:12] 9 18 10 12 19 5 13 10 2 3 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:61, 1:12] 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:61, 1:12] 4 10 16 15 8 14 10 23 11 5 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:61, 1:12] 0 1 4 4 5 3 0 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:65, 1:12] 165 100 177 65 148 58 188 55 59 62 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:65, 1:12] 13 0 0 2 2 3 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:66, 1:12] 157 58 101 92 15 21 73 80 78 75 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:66, 1:12] 8 6 1 0 6 2 2 6 10 9 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:87, 1:12] 1 2 5 6 8 3 3 3 2 3 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:83, 1:12] 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 13 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:81, 1:12] 0 0 1 0 3 5 3 0 2 7 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:81, 1:12] 33 81 94 30 5 36 16 90 121 182 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:81, 1:12] 10 11 16 6 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:81, 1:12] 7 0 0 2 1 3 1 4 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:81, 1:12] 1 0 5 0 2 3 1 0 1 1 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:95, 1:12] 30 160 116 130 444 515 225 135 108 175 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:95, 1:12] 12 1 0 10 3 3 0 4 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:95, 1:12] 1 0 0 0 3 3 1 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:95, 1:12] 11 42 61 23 41 56 81 6 83 82 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:95, 1:12] 1 2 5 3 6 4 2 8 28 1 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:95, 1:12] 283 192 377 216 207 261 394 262 262 554 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:94, 1:12] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:72, 1:12] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:72, 1:12] 5 3 0 2 13 27 6 2 12 36 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:72, 1:12] 0 2 2 0 1 0 1 4 2 2 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:72, 1:12] 0 0 1 0 3 1 0 4 1 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:67, 1:12] 27 7 18 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:67, 1:12] 10 2 1 10 7 0 0 1 1 4 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:67, 1:12] 14 17 9 20 13 20 18 13 10 7 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:64, 1:12] 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 3 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:64, 1:12] 3 0 1 0 2 7 13 14 4 2 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:64, 1:12] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:72, 1:12] 59 61 55 120 49 202 325 244 377 551 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:72, 1:12] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:72, 1:12] 0 3 1 0 1 0 0 0 4 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:72, 1:12] 5 12 6 9 15 10 15 27 15 9 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:72, 1:12] 7 0 3 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:72, 1:12] 0 0 0 0 89 0 19 3 3 2 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:61, 1:12] 5 3 5 3 3 29 46 140 49 24 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:63, 1:12] 23 0 0 0 0 60 7 73 13 19 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:95, 1:12] 7 96 28 2 9 5 8 190 166 1 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:95, 1:12] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ NA: num [1:95, 1:12] 4 0 2 6 6 11 6 5 6 9 ...
  .. [list output truncated]
 - attr(*, "header")=List of 3
  ..$ description: chr "MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: MACI64, Created on: Sun Dec  9 17:35:24 2012                                         "
  ..$ version    : chr "5"
  ..$ endian     : chr "little"
```

After loading the matlab file into R

```
all_exp_traintest$exp.traintest[1]
$<NA>
      [,1] [,2]  [,3]   [,4]   [,5]    [,6]     [,7]      [,8]       [,9]       [,10]        [,11]        [,12]
 [1,]    0  0.0  0.00  0.000 0.5000 0.03125 0.015625 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
 [2,]    0  0.0  0.00  1.000 0.0625 0.03125 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
 [3,]    0  0.0  2.00  0.125 0.0625 0.00000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
 [4,]    0  4.0  0.25  0.125 0.0000 0.00000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0009765625
 [5,]    8  0.5  0.25  0.000 0.0000 0.00000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0019531250 0.0000000000
 [6,]    1  0.5  0.00  0.000 0.0000 0.00000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.003906250 0.0000000000 0.0004882812
 [7,]    1  0.0  0.00  0.000 0.0000 0.00000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00781250 0.000000000 0.0009765625 0.0009765625
 [8,]    0  0.0  0.00  0.000 0.0000 0.00000 0.000000 0.0156250 0.00000000 0.001953125 0.0019531250 0.0000000000
 [9,]    0  0.0  0.00  0.000 0.0000 0.00000 0.031250 0.0000000 0.00390625 0.003906250 0.0000000000 0.0004882812
[10,]    0  0.0  0.00  0.000 0.0000 0.06250 0.000000 0.0078125 0.00781250 0.000000000 0.0009765625 0.0000000000
[11,]    0  0.0  0.00  0.000 0.1250 0.00000 0.015625 0.0156250 0.00000000 0.001953125 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
[12,]    0  0.0  0.00  0.250 0.0000 0.03125 0.031250 0.0000000 0.00390625 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0004882812
[13,]    0  0.0  0.50  0.000 0.0625 0.06250 0.000000 0.0078125 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0009765625 0.0000000000
[14,]    0  1.0  0.00  0.125 0.1250 0.00000 0.015625 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.001953125 0.0000000000 0.0024414062
[15,]    2  0.0  0.25  0.250 0.0000 0.03125 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00390625 0.000000000 0.0048828125 0.0014648438
[16,]    0  0.5  0.50  0.000 0.0625 0.00000 0.000000 0.0078125 0.00000000 0.009765625 0.0029296875 0.0039062500
[17,]    1  1.0  0.00  0.125 0.0000 0.00000 0.015625 0.0000000 0.01953125 0.005859375 0.0078125000 0.0151367188
[18,]    2  0.0  0.25  0.000 0.0000 0.03125 0.000000 0.0390625 0.01171875 0.015625000 0.0302734375 0.0019531250
[19,]    0  0.5  0.00  0.000 0.0625 0.00000 0.078125 0.0234375 0.03125000 0.060546875 0.0039062500 0.0029296875
[20,]    1  0.0  0.00  0.125 0.0000 0.15625 0.046875 0.0625000 0.12109375 0.007812500 0.0058593750 0.0253906250
[21,]    0  0.0  0.25  0.000 0.3125 0.09375 0.125000 0.2421875 0.01562500 0.011718750 0.0507812500 0.0253906250
[22,]    0  0.5  0.00  0.625 0.1875 0.25000 0.484375 0.0312500 0.02343750 0.101562500 0.0507812500 0.0063476562
[23,]    1  0.0  1.25  0.375 0.5000 0.96875 0.062500 0.0468750 0.20312500 0.101562500 0.0126953125 0.0009765625
[24,]    0  2.5  0.75  1.000 1.9375 0.12500 0.093750 0.4062500 0.20312500 0.025390625 0.0019531250 0.0000000000
[25,]    5  1.5  2.00  3.875 0.2500 0.18750 0.812500 0.4062500 0.05078125 0.003906250 0.0000000000 0.0019531250
[26,]    3  4.0  7.75  0.500 0.3750 1.62500 0.812500 0.1015625 0.00781250 0.000000000 0.0039062500 0.0029296875
[27,]    8 15.5  1.00  0.750 3.2500 1.62500 0.203125 0.0156250 0.00000000 0.007812500 0.0058593750 0.0009765625
[28,]   31  2.0  1.50  6.500 3.2500 0.40625 0.031250 0.0000000 0.01562500 0.011718750 0.0019531250 0.0000000000
[29,]    4  3.0 13.00  6.500 0.8125 0.06250 0.000000 0.0312500 0.02343750 0.003906250 0.0000000000 0.0083007812
[30,]    6 26.0 13.00  1.625 0.1250 0.00000 0.062500 0.0468750 0.00781250 0.000000000 0.0166015625 0.0000000000
[31,]   52 26.0  3.25  0.250 0.0000 0.12500 0.093750 0.0156250 0.00000000 0.033203125 0.0000000000 0.0048828125
[32,]   52  6.5  0.50  0.000 0.2500 0.18750 0.031250 0.0000000 0.06640625 0.000000000 0.0097656250 0.0034179688
[33,]   13  1.0  0.00  0.500 0.3750 0.06250 0.000000 0.1328125 0.00000000 0.019531250 0.0068359375 0.0229492188
[34,]    2  0.0  1.00  0.750 0.1250 0.00000 0.265625 0.0000000 0.03906250 0.013671875 0.0458984375 0.0297851562
[35,]    0  2.0  1.50  0.250 0.0000 0.53125 0.000000 0.0781250 0.02734375 0.091796875 0.0595703125 0.0771484375
[36,]    4  3.0  0.50  0.000 1.0625 0.00000 0.156250 0.0546875 0.18359375 0.119140625 0.1542968750 0.0004882812
[37,]    6  1.0  0.00  2.125 0.0000 0.31250 0.109375 0.3671875 0.23828125 0.308593750 0.0009765625 0.0000000000
[38,]    2  0.0  4.25  0.000 0.6250 0.21875 0.734375 0.4765625 0.61718750 0.001953125 0.0000000000 0.0048828125
[39,]    0  8.5  0.00  1.250 0.4375 1.46875 0.953125 1.2343750 0.00390625 0.000000000 0.0097656250 0.0000000000
[40,]   17  0.0  2.50  0.875 2.9375 1.90625 2.468750 0.0078125 0.00000000 0.019531250 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
[41,]    0  5.0  1.75  5.875 3.8125 4.93750 0.015625 0.0000000 0.03906250 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
[42,]   10  3.5 11.75  7.625 9.8750 0.03125 0.000000 0.0781250 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0004882812
[43,]    7 23.5 15.25 19.750 0.0625 0.00000 0.156250 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0009765625 0.0078125000
[44,]   47 30.5 39.50  0.125 0.0000 0.31250 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.001953125 0.0156250000 0.0000000000
[45,]   61 79.0  0.25  0.000 0.6250 0.00000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00390625 0.031250000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
[46,]  158  0.5  0.00  1.250 0.0000 0.00000 0.000000 0.0078125 0.06250000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0004882812
[47,]    1  0.0  2.50  0.000 0.0000 0.00000 0.015625 0.1250000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0009765625 0.0000000000
[48,]    0  5.0  0.00  0.000 0.0000 0.03125 0.250000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.001953125 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
[49,]   10  0.0  0.00  0.000 0.0625 0.50000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00390625 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
[50,]    0  0.0  0.00  0.125 1.0000 0.00000 0.000000 0.0078125 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
[51,]    0  0.0  0.25  2.000 0.0000 0.00000 0.015625 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
[52,]    0  0.5  4.00  0.000 0.0000 0.03125 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
[53,]    1  8.0  0.00  0.000 0.0625 0.00000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
[54,]   16  0.0  0.00  0.125 0.0000 0.00000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
[55,]    0  0.0  0.25  0.000 0.0000 0.00000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
[56,]    0  0.5  0.00  0.000 0.0000 0.00000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of the input file so that the problem can be reproduced?

Comment: Also, `str(all_exp_traintest)` would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks just added the structure of the file.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman: Or better yet, `dput(all_exp_traintest)`

Comment: I'm not able to read in that file using `readMat`. When you say it's the structure of the file, does that mean that if that were copy and pasted into a file it should be able to reproduce your problem? (again, `dput(all_exp_trainset)` might make things easier)

Comment: The _matlab_ file structure is just about the most useless piece of information you could possibly provide. Follow the advice above. If I had to guess I'd say that the problem here is a confusion between `[` and `[[` for lists. Also, don't use `$` as a variable selector in formulas. Just type the name of the variable.

Comment: Just added the first element of the list and reason I am using 302 plus is once I load the matlab file the labels which are in the second column of Matlab file end up at that location

Comment: @DavidRobinson its a matfile wit 300 rows and two columns [56x12 double] this has matrix inside

Comment: Well, you _definitely_ need to read about the difference between `[` and `[[` for selecting items from lists. They are very different, and you are using the wrong one. But I can't be sure that that will fix all your problems because you inexplicably are choosing to provide every piece of information _except_ what was originally requested: `str(all_exp_traintest)`.

Comment: very sorry adding it right now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I will explain for you the difference between `[` and `[[` that is causing you problems. I'll leave it to you to use this information to make the appropriate changes.

Consider the following list:

```
l <- list(a = matrix(1:25,5,5),b = 1:5,c = letters[1:5],d = NA)
> l
$a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25

$b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$c
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

$d
[1] NA
```

Say we want to select the first element of this list, i.e. the matrix. You are doing something like this:

```
> l[1]
$a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

This is wrong. `[` will always return a *sub-list* of the original list. So what you are seeing here with `l[1]` is actually a list of length one. It's one element is the matrix that we are actually after.

What you want instead is:

```
> l[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

If you compare the output of `str(l[1])` with `str(l[[1]])` the difference should be obvious, and also make clear why the first piece of information that was requested from you involved the output of `str`. It is an invaluable debugging tool, to ensure that the object is what you actually think it is.

Finally, as I mentioned in one of my comments, please never, ever do things like:

```
expert_data_frame$t_labels ~.
```

Rather, just do:

```
t_labels ~.
```

The whole point of the formula interface is that you don't have to write the name of the data frame. The function will look within the data frame you provide for the variables that you name in the formula. If you use `$` to explicitly select variables, you introduce a nasty source of bugs, whereby you will potentially force R to use a variable you didn't intend.

Comment: Fantastic overview, Thank you for the great tutorial on [ and [[, I manage to fix the problem